# Parse command line argument in python

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, argparse

have to do command line parsing and I am getting this error. I'm very new to Python and I don't know what the error means.

```
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-i", "--image", required=True,
    help="path to input image")
ap.add_argument("-m", "--mask-rcnn", required=True,
    help="base path to mask-rcnn directory")
ap.add_argument("-v", "--visualize", type=int, default=0,
    help="whether or not we are going to visualize each instance")
ap.add_argument("-c", "--confidence", type=float, default=0.5,
    help="minimum probability to filter weak detections")
ap.add_argument("-t", "--threshold", type=float, default=0.3,
    help="minimum threshold for pixel-wise mask segmentation")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())
```

I am getting this error:

> usage: **main**.py [-h] -i IMAGE -m MASK_RCNN [-v VISUALIZE] [-c CONFIDENCE]
>                      [-t THRESHOLD]
>   **main**.py: error: the following arguments are required: -i/--image, -m/--mask-rcnn
>
> An exception has occurred, use `%tb` to see the full traceback.
>
> SystemExit: 2
>
> C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py:2889: UserWarning: To exit: use 'exit', 'quit', or Ctrl-D.
>     warn("To exit: use 'exit', 'quit', or Ctrl-D.", stacklevel=1)

​

Comment: you passed `required=True` to `add_argument(...)`, so `-i` and `-m` is mandatory.

Comment: Do you want them to be required or not?  If so, then you must pass them on the command line.  If not, then you need to change your mind and remove the `require=True` that makes them required.  Should be pretty clear.

Comment: It is a requirement. I don't understand how to pass them on command line. Do i have to write this code on command line?

Comment: @VITTHALBHANDARI What command did you use to run it on the command line?

Comment: Show the command line that started this `ipython` session and used `main.py`.

Comment: I am working on jupyter notebook.

Comment: Why do you need to use argparse in that context?  The shell commandline starts the server, and provides server values. A server could run several notebooks.

Answer (score 0):

`argparse` processes the strings in the `sys.argv` list.  Normally this comes from the command line values provided when calling the script containing the `argparse` code:

```
$ python main.py -i foo -m bar
```

But it looks like you are using `ipython`.  It would be good to see how you call this script.  But you might need to use:

```
$ ipython -i main.py -- -i foo -m bar
```

The '--' separates the input that `ipython` uses from the input that it should make available to `main.py`.